# uncut files AWK : Random and strange

Tags: csv, awk

By using AWK (1.3.3) for Windows, we encountered a problem random and strange

We use AWK to cut csv files to integrate more easily into our application. The files arrive in the import directory every 9 minutes and are cut and then loaded, during all the day. The problem is that sometimes the files are not cut. This can happen one or more times in the same day or never.

When we return again not cut files in the import directory, cutting works well!

Does anybody have already encountered this problem and has an idea of the cause?

We use awk in .bat file like this:

```
REM arg1 = file to split
REM arg2 = max size
REM arg3 = destination folder
REM arg4 = AWK folder
REM If file arg1 size is smaller than arg2 then use column 1 else use column 3
cd %3 & if %~z1 LSS %2 (%4awk -F; "{print >> $1\".csv\"}" %1) else (%4awk -F; "{print >> $3\".csv\"}" %1)
```

Thank you in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

If by "the files are not cut" you mean that the whole lines are printed instead of just one column, then it might be a problem of file separator, for instance if some csv files have ',' as a file separator instead of ';' and you would have to change -F; by -F';|,'.

The best would be to see a problematic file individually.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

By "the files are not cut" I mean that nothing is happen, the target directory is empty.
I don’t think that problem come from files, because when I return again not cut files in the import directory, cutting works well.

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem with an escape character. You could try replacing " by ' and \" by "... Otherwise, could it come from the batch script itself? You could test if you actually are in one of the "if" cases and see if awk doesn't give any output.